# Django deployment using lightsail site-packages are not updated

Tags: package

I am trying to deploy my Django application on AWS Lightsail.

I've been following the AWS tutorial and thought got it quite well.
I've successfully tested application on 0.0.0.0:8000 and the app is working fine.

However, when I deployed with apache, it keeps giving me the Internal Error 500. Hence, I've gone to look up the error_logs to investigate.

Based on my investigation, it seems like all of pip packages I've installed for my app are not installed on system's python's site-packages.

This is the list of packages when I run pip list

```
pip list
```

Package             Version

---

appdirs             1.4.4
argon2-cffi         20.1.0
asgiref             3.2.10
astroid             2.4.2
async-generator     1.10
attrs               20.2.0
backcall            0.2.0
bleach              3.2.1
boto3               1.15.18
botocore            1.18.18
cffi                1.14.3
decorator           4.4.2
defusedxml          0.6.0
distlib             0.3.1
Django              3.1
django-carton       1.2.1
django-extensions   3.0.9
django-storages     1.10.1
entrypoints         0.3
filelock            3.0.12
importlib-metadata  2.0.0
ipykernel           5.3.4
ipython             7.16.1
ipython-genutils    0.2.0
ipywidgets          7.5.1
isort               5.6.4
jedi                0.17.2
Jinja2              2.11.2
jmespath            0.10.0
jsonschema          3.2.0
jupyter             1.0.0
jupyter-client      6.1.7
jupyter-console     6.2.0
jupyter-core        4.6.3
jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2
lazy-object-proxy   1.4.3
MarkupSafe          1.1.1
mccabe              0.6.1
mistune             0.8.4
mysqlclient         1.4.6
nbclient            0.5.1
nbconvert           6.0.7
nbformat            5.0.8
nest-asyncio        1.4.1
notebook            6.1.4
packaging           20.4
pandocfilters       1.4.2
parso               0.7.1
pexpect             4.8.0
pickleshare         0.7.5
Pillow              8.0.0
pip                 20.2.1
prometheus-client   0.8.0
prompt-toolkit      3.0.8
psycopg2            2.8.5
ptyprocess          0.6.0
pycparser           2.20
Pygments            2.7.1
pylint              2.6.0
pyparsing           2.4.7
pyrsistent          0.17.3
python-dateutil     2.8.1
pytz                2020.1
pyzmq               19.0.2
qtconsole           4.7.7
QtPy                1.9.0
s3transfer          0.3.3
Send2Trash          1.5.0
setuptools          46.4.0
six                 1.15.0
sorl-thumbnail      12.6.3
sqlparse            0.4.1
terminado           0.9.1
testpath            0.4.4
toml                0.10.1
tornado             6.0.4
traitlets           4.3.3
typed-ast           1.4.1
urllib3             1.25.10
virtualenv          20.0.30
wcwidth             0.2.5
webencodings        0.5.1
widgetsnbextension  3.5.1
wrapt               1.12.1
zipp                3.3.1

However, these are not shown in the site-packages folder.

```
bitnami@ip-172-26-7-56:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ ls
```

appdirs-1.4.4-py3.8.egg    mysqlclient-1.4.6-py3.8.egg-info  setuptools-46.4.0-py3.8.egg
asgiref                    MySQLdb                           setuptools.pth
asgiref-3.2.10.dist-info   pip-20.2.1-py3.8.egg              six-1.15.0-py3.8.egg
distlib-0.3.1-py3.8.egg    psycopg2                          sqlparse
django                     psycopg2-2.8.5-py3.8.egg-info     sqlparse-0.3.1.dist-info
Django-3.1-py3.8.egg-info  pytz                              virtualenv-20.0.30-py3.8.egg
easy-install.pth           pytz-2020.1.dist-info
filelock-3.0.12-py3.8.egg  README.txt

As a result, when the app is run by apache, there is internal server error and the packages I installed are not recognised.

I have spent about 3 days in a row trying to figure out deployment. For me, deployment is the most difficult task and I don't know where I am going. Would anyone recommend the easiest way to deploy django application?

Thanks a million!!